# ActualWidth and ActualHeight of custom control in grid are zero, even after measure/arrange

Tags: .net, xaml, windows-8, actualwidth, actualheight

I have a Win8 app with a custom control, GameView, which I have instantiated three times (as gvMap, gvOurBase, and gvEnemyBase) on my page, and placed into a grid. I need to get the actual size of the control so I can set the RenderTransform and render everything with the proper scaling.

However, whenever I attempt to get the `ActualWidth` or `ActualHeight` of my controls, I always get zero. This occurs even if I wait until the page is loaded and call Measure and Arrange on my controls.

How can I get the size of my controls? Or am I not allowed to do this while they are in a grid? Is there another way for me to do the RenderTransform that doesn't rely on the size of the controls? I want each control to show a specific section of the whole game map - gvMap shows the whole map, gvOurBase shows the section of the map that the player has cities, and gvEnemyBase shows the section of the map that the enemy has cities.

Comment: For ****'s n giggles, do you try to just grab the value to see it visually to confirm? Like <TextBlock Text="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=YourControl}" ? Or on another note, considered just planting them in a ViewBox to do your scaling for you?

Comment: I checked in the debugger where I was using the variables; they were indeed zero. I'll look into the ViewBox.

Comment: Nope, ViewBox is not what I want - I want to be able to scale only a specific section of the game map to a specific size, not a single control or the entire game map.

Answer (score 2):

That can happen. I recommend `MyControl.RenderSize.Width` instead of `MyControl.ActualWidth`. In layouts that result from dynamic data binding, `Actual` values aren't always populated.

Comment: Unfortunately, RenderSize is also (0,0).

Comment: Yea RenderSize gives me the correct with but not the correct height. ActualWidth and ActualHeight give also wrong numbers. Listening to the SizeChanged is also wrong size. (I have a grid in a grid)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I needed to actually override `MeasureOverride` on my custom control class. Oops!

Comment: I also found that setting the RenderTransform of the whole control wouldn't work, since that would let it overlap other controls. I had to do the scaling inside the control's own rendering logic.